# c# collections and array with textual keys and values

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, dictionary, collections

I can add rows of data to a datatable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("Id");
dt.Columns.Add("Title");
dt.Columns.Add("Description");

DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
r["Id"] = 1;
r["Title"] = "Article Title";
r["Description"] = "Article Description";
dt.Rows.Add(r);
```

Then output the necessary cell value.

```
MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString());
```

So it's a kind of array *( that contains rows )* of arrays *( each one having 3 textual keys and 3 textual values )*.

**Question:**

How can I use Collection variables to achieve this without a datatable?
Or maybe you could suggest any other type of data which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class to represent your object like this:

```
public class MyData //You can name this whatever makes sense in your case
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

And then you can create a `List<MyData>` like this:

```
List<MyData> list = new List<MyData>();

list.Add(
    new MyData
    {
        Id = 1,
        Title = "Article Title",
        Description = "Article Description"
    });
```

And access it like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(list[0].Title);
```